# How to define an array depending on the OS?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

My problem is that, depending on the OS, I need to declare an array containing the error text, but I can't figure out how to implement this using header files and preprocessor directives.

I have tried the following implementation but I am unable to access the desired array:

errorno.c:

```
#include "s21_errorno.h"

#ifdef __linux__
os_error[] = {"",
               "Operation not permitted",
               "No such file or directory",
               "No such process",
               "Interrupted system call",
               "I/O error",
               "No such device or address",
               "Argument list too long",
               "Exec format error",
               "Bad file number",
               "No child processes"};

#elif __APPLE__
os_error[] = {"",
              "Operation not permitted",
              "No such file or directory",
              "No such process",
              "Interrupted system call",
              "Input/output error",
              "Device not configured",
              "Argument list too long",
              "Exec format error",
              "Bad file descriptor",
              "No child processes"};

#endif
```

errorno.h:

```
#ifndef C2_S21_STRINGPLUS_0_S21_ERRORNO_H
#define C2_S21_STRINGPLUS_0_S21_ERRORNO_H

#define const char* os_error[]

#endif  // C2_S21_STRINGPLUS_0_S21_ERRORNO_H
```

main.c:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "s21_errorno.h"

int main() {

 for (int i = 0; i < 50 ; ++i) {
    printf("%s",os_error[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't access the array on what OS? I know clang will set the `__APPLE__` macro on mac platforms, I'm not sure off the top of my head what's set on Linux. Perhaps put in an else into the preprocessor conditional to detect if none of the supported systems are found?

Comment: one of my Linux macros, so this condition must be exactly fulfilled, the problem is that I can't implement it correctly...

Comment: I've just noticed in your header file you have `#define const char* os_error[]`. This should be `extern const char* os_error[];`. That should fix the compilation issue.

Comment: I might be tempted to deduplicate, i.e. only set the platform specific values.  +1 on the extern but don't you just set the value in the header file?  Why do you a define instead of a typedef?

Comment: Why do you use `#ifdef` in one place and `#elif` in another instead of `#if defined __linux__` and `#elif defined __APPLE__` in both or `#if __linux` and `#elif __APPLE__` in both? What do you want to happen if `__linux__` is defined and is set to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start from the header file. You need a **declaration** there: `extern const char *os_error[];`. This allows you to use that incomplete array of char pointers in every .c file that includes it.

Then in the .c file you need a **definition**: `const char *os_error[] = { /*stuff*/ };`

But your `os_error` is an incomplete array, so you cannot get its size with `sizeof`. It's probably useful to also define a `size_error` variable to report on the size of that array.

##### s21_errorno.h:

```
#ifndef S21_ERRORNO_H
#define S21_ERRORNO_H

#include <stdlib.h>

extern const char *os_error[];
extern size_t size_error;

#endif  // S21_ERRORNO_H
```

##### s21_errorno.c:

```
#include "s21_errorno.h"

#ifdef __linux__
const char *os_error[] = { "",
               "Operation not permitted",
               "No such file or directory",
               "No such process",
               "Interrupted system call",
               "I/O error",
               "No such device or address",
               "Argument list too long",
               "Exec format error",
               "Bad file number",
               "No child processes" };
size_t size_error = sizeof os_error / sizeof *os_error;

#elif __APPLE__
const char *os_error[] = { "",
              "Operation not permitted",
              "No such file or directory",
              "No such process",
              "Interrupted system call",
              "Input/output error",
              "Device not configured",
              "Argument list too long",
              "Exec format error",
              "Bad file descriptor",
              "No child processes" };
size_t size_error = sizeof os_error / sizeof *os_error;

#endif
```

##### main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "s21_errorno.h"

int main(void)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size_error; ++i) {
        printf("os_error[%d] = %s\n", i, os_error[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define the variable like this in your errno.c file to eliminate duplication:

```
const char *os_error[] = {
    "",
    "Operation not permitted",
    "No such file or directory",
    "No such process",
    "Interrupted system call",
#ifdef __linux__
    "I/O error",
    "No such device or address",
#elif __APPLE__
    "Input/output error",
    "Device not configured",
#endif
    "Argument list too long",
    "Exec format error",
    "Bad file number",
    "No child processes"
};
size_t size_error = sizeof os_error / sizeof *os_error;
```

The corresponding header definition in errno.h would be:

```
#ifndef ERRORNO_H
#define ERRORNO_H

extern const char *os_error[];
extern size_t size_error;

#endif
```

Comment: This won't work if you include the header file in multiple source files, because the linker will find the symbol defined multiple times.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana I will add the include guards to clarify answer.  To me it was obvious.

Comment: A header guard does not help against the multiple definitions, it only helps with multiple inclusions. A completely correct solution needs to separate declaration (in the header file) and definition (in the implementation translation unit), as the accepted answer shows. However, some linkers allow such multiple definitions and ignore them silently.

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks for writing that up.  In my mind the pre-processor would ensure the compiler only saw that part of the file once, but clearly that is not the case.  Updated answer for good measure.

Comment: Sure, the **compiler** sees it only once. But if you include such a header in multiple compiled files, such a variable is defined in each of the translation units. The **linker** is the first that sees the problem. You need to differentiate these tools clearly.